# All Elements in Dictionary have the same length, is there an easy way to work on all elements simultaneously

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, dictionary

(first question - constructive feedback on how to ask questions appreciated)

In my new job I have taken over some code where data is stored columnwise as ndarrays in a dictionary. So its originally from a database, and each column is stored in an array, and the arrays are stored in a dictionary. Example with arbitrary data:

```
MAP = {'ID': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), 
       'City': array(['Berlin', 'Copenhagen', 'London', 'Rome', 'Zurich'], dtype='<U10'),
       'Population': array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14])}
```

As far as I know, this was done for performance reasons. Now I need to perform some operations on this, like sorting and deleting "rows". the only way I can think of to do this is to either put it all into a DataFrame, do the operations there and then isolate the columns back into dict format, or to work with the index and do it on each array individually. Both do not seem ideal to me, so my question is: Is there a way to efficiently perform these actions on all elements in my dictionary?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I'll go with the first approach

Comment: That's the format Pandas dataframes internally use, so it might make sense to use Pandas for that.

Comment: Seems like the coder chose a weird way to do tables to sacrifice extensibility for performance in a certain context. Unless you want to spend time rewriting all the code for dataframes or writing a lot of pandas-like functions for a dict of arrays, I'd make do with conversion between the two data structures. It's not convenient because you may have to manage the order of your operations to avoid wasting time on too many conversions, but I think that is still far easier than rewriting code.

Comment: Thanks, did not know that @AKX , and everyone else for corroborating it!